# Affine equivalence of hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

I am studying the affine equivalence of conics and quadrics (in $R^2$ and $R^3$), and I've read that all hyperplanes are affinely equivalent (I think the statement is generally referred to $R^n$ space). Can I prove this by simply saying that if I take $n$ points on one hyperplane and $n$ on the other,it always exists an affinity which sends the firsts to the seconds? If not, how could I prove this fact?

Comment: If you are in affine geometry, you are dependent of the type of the conic. For example, 2 hyperbolas $H_1$ and $H_2$ being given there is at least one affine transformation that will map $H_1$ onto $H_2$; But if $E$ is an ellipse, no affine transform will map (the bounded curve) $E$ onto (the unbounded curve) $H_1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant hyperplanes (that is affine subspaces of dimension $n-1$), I have changed the post.